# Grails command objects validating fields based on the value of other fields

Tags: validation, grails, command-objects

I have a command object

```
@Validateable
class PropertyDetailsCommand implements Serializable {
   Boolean ownerOccupied
   String personalDescription

    static constraints = {

        personalDescription validator:{value, obj, errs->
             if(obj.ownerOccupied==true)
             {
               if(!value)
                 errs.rejectValue('personalDescription','propertyDetailsCommand.personalDescription.blank')

             }

         }

    }

 }
```

I found that when the statement

```
 if(obj.ownerOccupied==true)
```

is present, the validation does not work.

I tries by adding

```
static mapping={
    ownerOccupied lazy:false
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: The lazy setting in the mapping will not do anything, since ownerOccupied is not a domain but a simple type. The if statement should be something like "if (obj.ownerOccupied)" since you can use Groovy truth here (and that will return false when ownerOccupied is null, which is possible in your model)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
@Validateable
class PropertyDetailsCommand implements Serializable {
    Boolean ownerOccupied
    String personalDescription

    static constraints = {
        personalDescription validator:{value, obj ->
            if(obj.ownerOccupied && !value) {
                return 'blank'
            }
        }
    }
}
```